# how replace self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem() } with button action

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

I replace BarButtonItem's `self.editButtonItem()` with button @IBAction..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   ....
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

I delete `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()`
above code

I wanna replace @IBAction button () { ***code*** }...

what's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution is this. Connect the nav button outlet action to this function

```
@IBAction func startEditBtnAct(_ sender: Any) {
        tableview.isEditing = !tableview.isEditing

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `leftBarButtonItem` **action** to a function, you can do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = "functionName:"
}

func functionName(sender: AnyObject!) {
    //Do something
}
```

**EDITED:**
If you want to set the tableview to edit mode, use the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func doEdit(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        editButton.title = "Edit"
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        editButton.title = "Done"
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: ah i write lack of expression..i don't wanna use navigationButtonItem, but I use UIButton..so I insert UIButton in navigationBar

i wanna UIButton to set tableview to editmode

Comment: @Gundam I edited the answer to include a function to programmatically set the tableview to edit mode and back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "buttonAction:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender:AnyObject?)
{
     //do your thing
}
```

Comment: i don't use BarButtonItem..

so insert UIButton in navigationBar

UIButton have @IBAction func

How UIButton do tableview edit mode?